# Angular: Not able to view response header in console

Tags: javascript, angular, http, observable

I'm able to view the response header data in the network tab request, however, I can't view the response headers when I'm logging the request in the console. For example, I can view x-pagination header property on the network tab but can't view it in the console. I can only view this in the console under headers --

headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}

Comment: what if you console.log `headers.get('x-pagination');`

Comment: Comes back as null

Comment: Ok I'm getting it back but it's coming back as a string and not an object

Comment: Can you the actual http function? Are you doing map to json by change in your request's response capture observable?

Comment: return this.http.get('api/v1/', {
            params: newParams, observe: 'response'
        }) . I don't need to include to json because I'm using HttpClient and it automatically does it for me.

Comment: Headers should be sent/received as strings. If you are needing an object, then you should be converting your object to a string on your server, passing it in the header, then parsing it back to an object in the client.

Comment: How would I parse it again? Would I Regex it?

Comment: Just remove the quotes?

Comment: Assuming it is a json string, you could use `JSON.parse()`